# Are $\mathbb{Q}[x],\mathbb{R}[x]$ unique factorization domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are fields, then are $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]$ ufds?

Is Eisenstein's criterion applies to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but not $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Comment: Yes, they are UFDs (in fact, PIDs). Eisenstein's criterion is a statement about $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, not $\mathbb{R}[x]$. For instance, $x^2-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by Eisenstein, but it factors in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: so this criterion can be applied to both Q[x] and R[x],right?

Comment: but why we can apply it to R[x,y]? thanks!

Comment: What's your statement of "Eisenstein but for $\mathbb{R}$"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they both are UFDs. They're even Euclidean domains, by way of the Euclidean function "take the degree of the polynomial".